# TextField does not unfocus when keyboard is hidden - Material 3 Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, material3

I'm facing a problem and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. When I implement a Material3 TextField when you hide the keyboard manually the Textfield is not loosing the focus and you can't open the keyboard again.

Is someone facing the same issue?

I am not inserting code snippet because is the simple TextField of material3:

```
        TextField(
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {}
        )
```

Here on this GIF you can see what it's happening, you click on the TextField, it focus and opens the keyboard correctly, then you manually hide the keyboard, the TextField keeps on focus and does not let you to open again the keyboard.

I'm using the version "1.2.0-beta02" of material3 for Jetpack compose

[image: gif of that it's happening]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/311437241) in Jetpack Compose that was already fixed in the latest library version.
Make sure that you are using the latest Jetpack Compose dependencies as follows:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta02"
```

Please report back if this resolves your issue.